# Banner ads bottom positioning with some space below

Tags: java, android, ads, banner-ads, appodeal

I am using Appodeal.show(getActivity(),Appodeal.BANNER_BOTTOM); to position banner ad at the bottom of screen , but i want to keep some space between the ad and the bottom of the screen around 20dp because there is a share button which gets covered by the ad.
So , how to position the bottom banner ad leaving some space below using java.

Comment: have you tried using margin to the adview ?

Comment: Actually i didn't write any code in xml for displaying the ad. I want to change the ad position using java code only, is it possible?

Comment: are you using admob ?

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: nope..i am using appodeal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the desired margins using something like this. Just call this method whenever you are creating the `adview`.

```
private void setBottomMargins (AdView adView, int bottomMargin) {
    if (adView.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
      ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) adView.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, bottomMargin);
      adView.requestLayout();
    }
  }
```